# testing stripe on-boarding django with mock

Tags: django, mocking, stripe-payments

i am having trouble trying to mock test the on-boarding process of stripe connect. I am just learning how to use mock and i am struggling with the StripeAuthorizeCallbackView. the process is as follows: A user reaches the StripeAuthorizeView which sends them to the stripe api to sign up for an account. Once they successfully sign up for an account their redirected back to my platform and stripe sends a temporary code which i then send back to stripe with my api keys. Once i have sent the information back to stripe they then return me credentials for the user being the stripe_user_id.

Here is the two views in question:

```
import urllib
import requests


class StripeAuthorizeView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

    def get(self, request):

        url = 'https://connect.stripe.com/express/oauth/authorize?'
        user = self.request.user
        if user.account_type == 'Business':
            business_type = 'company'
        else:
            business_type = 'individual'
        params = {
            'response_type': 'code',
            'scope': 'read_write',
            'client_id': settings.STRIPE_CONNECT_CLIENT_ID,
            'redirect_uri': f'http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/stripe/oauth/callback',
            'stripe_user[email]' : user.email,
            'stripe_user[business_type]' : business_type,
            'stripe_user[url]' : 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/user/%s/' %user.pk,
        }
        url = f'{url}?{urllib.parse.urlencode(params)}'
        return redirect(url)

lass StripeAuthorizeCallbackView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

    def get(self, request):
        code = request.GET.get('code')
        if code:
            data = {
                'client_secret': settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY,
                'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
                'client_id': settings.STRIPE_CONNECT_CLIENT_ID,
                'code': code
            }

            url = 'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token'
            resp = requests.post(url, params=data)


            stripe_user_id = resp.json()['stripe_user_id']
            stripe_access_token = resp.json()['access_token']
            stripe_refresh_token = resp.json()['refresh_token']
            user = self.request.user
            user.stripe_access_token = stripe_access_token
            user.stripe_user_id = stripe_user_id
            user.stripe_refresh_token = stripe_refresh_token
            user.save()
            notify.send(sender=user, recipient=user, 
            verb='You have succesfully linked a stripe account. You can now take payments for sales.',
            level='info')
            redirect_url = reverse('account', kwargs={'pk': user.pk}) 
            response = redirect(redirect_url)
            return response

        else:
            user = self.request.user
            notify.send(sender=user, recipient=user, 
            verb='Your attempt to link a stripe account failed. Please contact customer support.',
            level='warning')
            url = reverse('account', kwargs={'pk': user.pk}) 
            response = redirect(url)
            return response
```

I am not very worried about testing the StripeAuthorizeView a lot. I am more trying to figure out how to test the StripeAuthorizeCallbackView. All i can figure out is that i will need to mock both the code returned and then mock the following requests.post. This test is important to confirm my platform is linking the users credentials after the on-boarding process. Any help on this will be greatly appricated.

edit:
So far i have the following :

```
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.test_user = User.objects.create_user(
            password='test',
            full_name='test name',
            email='test@test.com',
            address='1 test st',
            suburb='test',
            state='NSW',
            post_code='2000',
            contact_number='0433335333' )

    @patch('requests.get')
    def test_authorizecallback_creates_stripe_details(self, get_mock):
        code = requests.get('code')
        user = self.test_user
        self.client.login(email='test@test.com', password='test')
        mocked = ({'stripe_user_id' : '4444','stripe_access_token' : '2222', 
        'stripe_refresh_token' : '1111' })

        with mock.patch('requests.post', mock.Mock(return_value=mocked)):
            response = self.client.get('/accounts/stripe/oauth/callback/', 
            {'code' : '1234'})
            self.assertEqual(user.stripe_access_token, '222')
            message = list(response.context.get('messages'))[0]
```

however i keep getting:

```
  File "C:\Users\typef\Desktop\Projects\python_env\fox-listed\Fox-Listed\fox-listed\user\views.py", line 142, in get
    stripe_user_id = resp.json()['stripe_user_id']
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'json'
```

the actual response that the StripeAuthorizeCallBackView gives is:

{'access_token': 'sk_test_1KyTG74Ouw65KYTR1O03WjNA00viNjcIfO', 'livemode': False, 'refresh_token': 'rt_H3Vrhd0XbSH7zbmqfDyMNwolgt1Gd7r4ESBDBr5a4VkCzTRT', 'token_type': 'bearer', 'stripe_publishable_key': 'pk_test_**********', 'stripe_user_id': 'acct_1GVOpAF7ag87i2I6', 'scope': 'express'}

Answer (score 1):

Looks like i got it, if there is a flaw here let me know but here is what i have:

```
class TestStripeAuthorizeCallbackView:

    @patch('user.views.requests')
    def test_authorizecallback_creates_stripe_details(self, requests_mock):
        json = { 'stripe_user_id' : '4444', 'access_token' : '2222', 'refresh_token' : '1111'} 


        requests_mock.post.return_value.json.return_value = json
        user = mixer.blend('user.CustomUser', stripe_user_id=None, access_token=None, refresh_token=None)
        req = RequestFactory().get('/', data={'code' : '1234'})
        middleware = SessionMiddleware()
        middleware.process_request(req)
        req.session.save()
        messages = FallbackStorage(req)
        setattr(req, '_messages', messages)

        req.user = user
        resp = StripeAuthorizeCallbackView.as_view()(req)

        assert resp.status_code == 302 ,'should redirect to success url'
        assert user.stripe_user_id == '4444', 'should assign stripe_user_id to user'
        assert user.stripe_access_token == '2222', 'should assign an access_token'
        assert user.stripe_refresh_token == '1111', 'should assign a refresh_token'
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing isn't mocking so much as it is end-to-end testing, [connecting actual test accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing#using-oauth), which you can do.

As long as you're using a **test** `client_id` then when you are redirected to Stripe to create the account you can *skip* the form via a link and get directed back to your site with a real (test mode) oauth code.

Essentially you can set this up and actually go through the flow to create & connect new disposable test Stripe accounts.

Comment: what do i need to do to skip the form?. So your saying i dont even need to mock the test? i can just test the actual functionality ?

Comment: That's right, when you follow the link to Stripe's account form in test mode (using a test mode `client_id`) you should see a link in the right side of the top banner allowing you to skip the form. Seen here: https://imgur.com/a/yIb0Kd2

Comment: You can try this out and see it by clicking the button in the docs here: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts#integrating-oauth